# Create a Maven project in Eclipse luna complains “Could not resolve archetype”

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

> Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:1.0 from any of the configured repositories.
>   Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0
>   Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
>   Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a company network, this is most probably a network/proxy issue.

Comment: @AnandPipalwa I do not completely understand your question. You should know whether you are at home or working in a company. Companies often have restrictions on outgoing and incoming network traffic - furthermore they often use proxies that have to be configured.